# How do I make FxCop understand a 'multi-case' word?

Tags: c#, fxcop

I work in a company that their acronym is something like `XyZ` (uppercase followed by lowercase than followed by uppercase again).

This word is spread across all our namespaces. When I run FxCop against our projects it accuses `IdentifiersShouldBeCasedCorrectly` ([CA1709](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms182240.aspx)). The suggestion is to capitalize just the first letter (what I don't want).

**How do I make FxCop understand that the word `XyZ` is known, spelled correctly and properly cased? (In other words, that is *well-written*)**.

I added the word to the `CustomDictionary.xml` file: I've added to `Recognized` words; `Unrecognized` words; and also`Acronyms` with `CasingExceptions`. None of these made any effect.

I also verified that FxCop is indeed reading the custom dictionary file, when I add another word in the acronym it stops reporting as a casing error as expected (but only for all caps words).

I'm using FxCop 1.36 (the GUI one) with C# projects.

---

**Update**

Adding just `Xy` to casing exceptions seems to make FxCop ignore `XyZ` as I want.

Still not a great solution since it will allow wrong words like `XyX` or `XyW` when the (only) correct one is `XyZ`.

Comment: No, the suggestion is *not* to capitalize the whole thing. The .NET naming convention is to use `Abc`, *even* if it is normally always written `ABC`, or in your case `AbC`. This is explained directly on the page you link to, which also includes some examples of that rule: `SQL` (not mentioned there) and `XML` (mentioned there) are normally always fully capitalized, but in .NET classes and methods, become `Sql` and `Xml`.

Comment: @hvd, you're right; corrected. My problem remains the same though.

Comment: Personally, I'd just suppress the FxCop rule: the detection of a violation of the rule is correct, and the violation of the rule is intentional, so diagnosing it doesn't help you. But I can understand that that may not be your preferred solution.

Comment: I agree with @hvd. By the rule FxCop is imposing, the "correct" way to use the term *XyZ* as part of an identifier is *Xyz*. Either follow the rule and rename any case of `XyZStuff` as `XyzStuff` and so on, or else turn off the rule because you've consciously decided not to follow it.

Comment: @JonHanna, yeah but it would be a poor solution to ignore the rule (that I want to follow for all other cases) just because I can't add the company name as an exception. This is not only a matter of a single developer in a single project, this will later become a step in our *continuous integration* server (affecting the whole development team). I still hope to find something better.

Comment: I'd be tempted to say that `XyZ` are at fault for having such an inconsistent exception rather than taking a "sauce for the goose" approach. The best I can think of is that you could turn off rule CA1709 and add a custom rule that duplicates it, bar for the case of `XyZ`.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `XyZ` to an FxCop dictionary - see [How to: Customize the Code Analysis Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb514188.aspx).

```
Code Analysis uses a built-in dictionary to check identifiers in your code for
errors in spelling, grammatical case, and other naming conventions of the .NET
Framework guidelines. You can create a custom dictionary Xml file to add, 
remove, or modify terms, abbreviations, and acronyms to the built-in dictionary.
```

**Dictionary/Acronyms/CasingExceptions/Acronym**

```
<Dictionary>
      <Acronyms>
         <CasingExceptions>
            <Acronym>NESW</Acronym>   <!-- North East South West -->
            ...
         </CasingExceptions>
         ...
      </Acronyms>
      ...
</Dictionary>
```

Terms in the Dictionary/Acronyms/CasingExceptions node are applied to the following code analysis rules:

```
CA1709: Identifiers should be cased correctly
```